# how to get multi route between two point by routing.openstreetmap.de?

Tags: android, routes, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I use openstreetmap api for routing between two points in Android Studio.
I want have several suggested routes.
I use the following address to send the request

```
https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-car/route/v1/driving/Origin.lon,Origin.lat;Destination.lon,Destination.lat?geometries=polyline&steps=true
```

But there is a one route is in json.
In Json, I would like to have a few suggestions of route

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported at the moment as far as I can tell. You can set via-Points or switch to a different [OSM-based online router](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using osmdroid, you can add OSMBonusPack lib to easily access to 3 different routing engines.
Among these 3, both OSRM and GraphHopper can provide alternate routes.

See https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/WhichRoutingService